# Use laws of logarithms to expand $\ln\left(2b\sqrt{\frac{b+1}{b-1}}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am to expand $\ln\left(2b\sqrt{\frac{b+1}{b-1}}\right)$ using the laws of logarithms. The solution is provided as $\ln(2)+\ln(b)+\frac{\ln(b+1)-\ln(b-1)}{2}$ whereas I got $\ln(2)+\ln(b)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(b+1)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(b-1)$

My working:
$$\ln\left(2b\sqrt{\frac{b+1}{b-1}}\right)$$
$$=\ln(2)+\ln(b)+\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{b+1}{b-1}}\right)$$
$$=\ln(2)+\ln(b)+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{b+1}{b-1}\right)$$
$$=\ln(2)+\ln(b)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(b+1)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(b-1).$$

I suspect that I might have made a mistake using the power rule to use $1/2$ for the root of the expression $\frac{b+1}{b-1}$, but I'm unsure.

How can I arrive at the correct solution?

Comment: And where do you spot any difference between your and the reference solution? -- Admittedly, you made two steps at once in your last step, but nothing wrong

Comment: Your answer is completely right. In fact, I like your answer more. It's more... "expanded" looking lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2}A-\frac{1}{2}B=\frac{A-B}{2}$$

where $A=\ln(b+1)$, $B=\ln(b-1)$.

In short, you arrived at the given answer.

Comment: I went away and came back to my computer. I see it now clear as day. D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

Just, take $\frac{1}{2}$ common from last two terms, you got the correct answer.